# How can I set a delay for next scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need set a one second delay for next scroll event, after scrolling. How can I achieve this?

```
$('body').scrollTop(100);
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var BS = $('body').scrollTop();

    if(BS > 101){
        /* Disable scroll for 1 sec Delay */
    }else if(BS < 98) {
        /* Disable scroll for 1 sec Delay */
    }

    $('body').scrollTop(100);
});
```

Like this [page](http://ivang-design.com/hera/index.html)
 - after you've scrolled, your mouse wheel doesn't work for one second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a timer to momentarily disable your function:

```
var
    scrollEnabled = true;

$('body').scrollTop(100);

function disableScroll() {
    // temporarily disable action
    scrollEnabled = false;

    // set a timer to enable again it 1 second from now
    setTimeout(function() {
        scrollEnabled = true;
    }, 1000);
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var bs;

    if (scrollEnabled) {
        bs = $('body').scrollTop();

        if (bs > 101 || bs < 98) {
            disableScroll();
        }

        $('body').scrollTop(100);
    }
});
```

Comment: How does that prevent scrolling?

Comment: Thank you a lot men . you are great. that was my problem for 2 days xD

Comment: @nnnnnn You can't actually disable scrolling itself, but you can disable your what your code is doing when it happens - exactly what the OP wants. In fact, the page that the OP refers to is using absolute position for its divs and some CSS wizardry; that's why you don't see the page scrolling.